# Remove White Space from ExpressionEngine Templates

Tags: html, templates, expressionengine

I was wondering if there was a way to strip the extra white space created by EE's template system and produce "prettier" markup.

I like to keep my templates readable. I often times come back to jobs years later, have to follow other developers' work, or work as part of a team, and it's easier when everything is neat and nested.

The problem is that EE preserves all of the tabs and line breaks, and when you have a lot of conditionals and such, it results in ugly code. For example, this:

```
<div class="
    event {if event_all_day}all_day{/if} 
    {if event_multi_day}multi_day{/if} 
    {if event_first_day}first_day{/if} 
    {if event_last_day}last_day{/if} 
    {if all_day_event_index_difference > 0}index_difference_{all_day_event_index_difference}{/if}
">
    {if event_multi_day} 
        <a href="{path='calendar_main/event'}/{event_id}/">{event_title}</a>
    {if:else}
        <a href="{path='calendar_main/event'}/{if edited_occurrence}{event_parent_id}{if:else}{event_id}{/if}/" title="{event_title}">{event_title}</a>
    {/if}
</div>
```

Renders into this:

```
<div class="
                                         event all_day 
                                         multi_day 


                                                                               ">

                                         <a href="http://www.downtownmuncie.org/calendar_main/event/1832/">Minnetrista Glass Show</a>
                                                                       </div>
```

Every tab and line-break surrounding the EE tags is preserved, so I wind up with a mile of white space between the `<div>` and `</div>`.

Performance-wise, it doesn't mean a thing. There may be an argument to be made for an increase in file size, but it's negligible. It's also a bit of a hinderance when trying to navigate through the code using Firebug.

But most of all, it just looks sloppy.

One suggestion is to adjust the templates accordingly, like so:

```
<div class="event {if event_all_day}all_day {/if}{if event_multi_day}multi_day {/if}{if event_first_day}first_day {/if}{if event_last_day}last_day {/if}{if all_day_event_index_difference > 0} index_difference_{all_day_event_index_difference}{/if}">
    {if event_multi_day}<a href="{path='calendar_main/event'}/{event_id}/">{event_title}</a>{if:else}<a href="{path='calendar_main/event'}/{if edited_occurrence}{event_parent_id}{if:else}{event_id}{/if}/" title="{event_title}">{event_title}</a>{/if}
</div>
```

That's not really a viable solution. Given the choice between neat templates and neat code, I'd have to go with the former.

Is there any way to have both?

ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `tidy_template` extension that uses the `template_post_parse` hook in EE, assuming you have 2.4.0 or newer.

https://github.com/sjelfull/sf.tidy_template.ee_addon

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're looking for a automatic or manual solution.  I'm not aware of anything automatic, but I'm sure someone more awesome can help with that.  I'm a fan of manual, so use a "real" editor on my EE templates, employing [It's All Text](http://bit.ly/NAbe5R) in FF to make the connection between these text areas and my editor.  At that point you can impose whatever whitespace rules on your templates your philosophy dictates.

Answer (score 0):

[AutoMin for EE by Jesse Bunch](https://github.com/bunchjesse/AutoMin) has an HTML compression feature. It won't beautify your indentation like HTMLTidy, but will remove all whitespace to reduce filesize.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but in similar situations (can't honestly remember if it was EE or not) I've put the whitespace inside the server side code.  Thus:

```
<div class="event {if
    event_all_day}all_day {/if}{if
    event_multi_day}multi_day {/if}{if
    event_first_day}first_day {/if}{if
    event_last_day }last_day {/if}{if
    all_day_event_index_difference > 0}index_difference_{all_day_event_index_difference{/if}
">
    {if
        event_multi_day}<a href="{path='calendar_main/event'}/{event_id}/">{event_title}</a>
    {if:else
    }<a href="{path='calendar_main/event'}/{if edited_occurrence}{event_parent_id}{if:else
    }     {event_id}{/if}/" title="{event_title}">{event_title}</a>
    {/if}
</div>
```